# Applying a style to ItemContainerStyle in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox, coding-style

When I'm applying a Style to a ListBox.ItemContainerStyle in C# it isn't making the change at runtime.

I'm using;

```
myListBox.ItemContainerStyle = (Style)(App.Current.Resources["NewItemStyle"]);
```

However all other styles are being supplied, such as Buttons etc where I'm going
`myButton.Style = (Style)(App.Current.Resources["myMainButtonStyle"]);`

I don't get any errors either, it just does nothing and reverts to the default system style.

Answer (score 0):

I was using App.Current.Resources instead of just Resources because "NewItemStyle" wasn't defined in the whole application. My mistake.